# How to parse this text file format into CSV format?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, formatting

I have a text file laid out as such where every field is a new line:

```
id = 606149
Category Name = Structural Columns
Family Name = Concrete-Square-Column
Type Name = EXIST RH C1 16 x 16
Document = 15050 Peavy Struct v2016_detached
Attachment Justification At Top = Minimum Intersection
Image = <None>
Offset From Attachment At Top = 0
id = 606151
Category Name = Structural Columns
Family Name = Concrete-Square-Column
Type Name = EXIST RH C2 16 x 16
Document = 15050 Peavy Struct v2016_detached
Attachment Justification At Top = Minimum Intersection
Image = <None>
Offset From Attachment At Top = 0
```

In my code I open the text file for reading and print out the first three lines for testing. When I try to append a comma to the end of the line I get the comma in the line below:

```
def main():
   count = 0
   filename = "test.txt"
   file = open(filename, "r")
   for line in file:
      if count == 3:
         break
      count = count + 1
      line += ','
      print line
```

With this code I get the result:

```
id = 606149
,
Category Name = Structural Columns
,
Family Name = Concrete-Square-Column
,
```

When I add a line strip to strip new lines before I concatenate the comma:

```
line = line.strip('\n')"
```

I get this result:

```
,id = 606149
,ategory Name = Structural Columns
,amily Name = Concrete-Square-Column
```

I'm having trouble parsing this file into a CSV format.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what the desired output would be from parsing the input shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can read whole file and split lines

```
filename = "text.txt"
file = open(filename, "r")

f = file.read().splitlines()
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to get desired o/p, But that count you have to mention :

```
with open('j.txt', 'r') as f:
d =f.readlines()
for i in d:
    i = i.rstrip('\n')
    i+=','
    print(i)
```

I have used `rstrip` here and it will print all the lines, for first three lines you can give some loop or condition.
O/P is something like this :

> id = 606149, 
>   Category Name = Structural Columns, 
>   Family Name =
>   Concrete-Square-Column,
>    Type Name = EXIST RH C1 16 x 16, 
>   Document =
>   15050 Peavy Struct v2016_detached,
>    Attachment Justification, At Top =
>   Minimum Intersection, 
>   Image = Offset From Attachment At Top = 0,

Answer (score 0):

If your data file is structured as shown above you could use the '=' to separatte each key value pair, store these to a dictionary for each row then after you've read each record completely (i.e. found the 'Offset...' key value) start another row.

Once you have all the data use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write your csv file.

```
import csv

data = []
with open('test.txt') as fin:
    row = {}
    for line in fin:
        key, val = line.strip().split(' = ')
        row[key] = val
        if key == 'Offset From Attachment At Top':
            data.append(row)
            row = {}

fieldnames = data[0].keys()
with open('test.csv') as fout:
    cw = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames)
    cw.writerows(data)
```

You probably want to add some error checking and may want to constrain the order of the field names in the call to `DictWriter`.  I suggest you make each row an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
line.rstrip("\n") + ","
```