# Parse Text File and Format as CSV

Tags: python, csv

So before I posted this question I found one similar to my question but not exact.
[How to parse this text file format into CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48537209/how-to-parse-this-text-file-format-into-csv-format)

I have a text file that I need to parse.

> TICKET NUMBER:2423
>   OLD SOURCE IPIP: 1.1.1.1
>   OLD SOURCE PORT: 50
>   HOST IP:2.2.2.2
>   HOST PORT: 52
>   EXPLOIT:SomeRANDOMexploit
>   Bunch of random email header garabage
>   TICKET NUMBER:2423
>   OLD SOURCE IPIP: 1.1.1.1
>   OLD SOURCE PORT: 50
>   HOST IP:2.2.2.2
>   HOST PORT: 52
>   EXPLOIT:SomeRANDOMexploit

I want to parse out all of the "Bunch of random email header garbage"
After it is parsed I would like to format the text to be read in a CSV file and create Headers and then only import the data below in columns. The end result should look like this:

> TICKET NUMBER, OLD SOURCE IPIP, OLD SOURCE PORT, HOST IP, HOST PORT, EXPLOIT
>     2423, 1.1.1.1, 50, 2.2.2.2, 52, SomeRANDOMexploit
>     2423, 1.1.1.1, 50, 2.2.2.2, 52, SomeRANDOMexploit

I found a way to parse out the lines using this code:

```py
import re

filename = "./input.txt"
infile = open(filename, 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()
lines[0:13]

for line in lines:
    if re.match("TICKET NUMBER|OLD SOURCE IP|OLD SOURCE PORT|HOST IP|HOST PORT|EXPLOIT", line):
        print(line.strip())

infile.close()
```

That gets rid of the email header garbage.
I just don't know how to take the data and then format it into a CSV where the colon can delimit it and place the Headers at the top of the column.

```py
import csv
with open('output.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = [line.replace(":","").split() for line in in_file]
    zipped = zip([stripped]*1)

    with open('out_file.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('TICKET NUMBER', 'OLD SOURCE IPIP', 'OLD SOURCE PORT', 'HOST IP', 'HOST PORT', 'EXPLOIT'))
        for group in zipped:
            writer.writerows(group)
```

The code above lets me write the Headers just fine but it prints everything form my text file into seperate columns all in the same row

**Output**

```
TICKET NUMBER, OLD SOURCE IPIP, OLD SOURCE PORT, HOST IP, HOST PORT, EXPLOIT  
['TICKET', 'NUMBER2423']    ['OLD', 'SOURCE', 'IPIP', '1.1.1.1']    ['OLD', 'SOURCE', 'PORT', '50'] ['HOST', 'IP2.2.2.2']   ['HOST', 'PORT']    ['EXPLOITSomeRANDOMexploit']    ['TICKET', 'NUMBER2423']    ['OLD', 'SOURCE', 'IPIP', '1.1.1.1']    ['OLD', 'SOURCE', 'PORT', '50'] ['HOST', 'IP2.2.2.2']   ['HOST', 'PORT']    ['EXPLOITSomeRANDOMexploit']
```

**Desired Output**

```
TICKET NUMBER, OLD SOURCE IPIP, OLD SOURCE PORT, HOST IP, HOST PORT, EXPLOIT  
2423, 1.1.1.1, 50, 2.2.2.2, 52, SomeRANDOMexploit  
2423, 1.1.1.1, 50, 2.2.2.2, 52, SomeRANDOMexploit
```

From what I understand the code is replacing the colon with nothing which then joins the two words into one. Also I don't know how to get them to print to a new line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a txt file to csv file in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715439/how-to-convert-a-txt-file-to-csv-file-in-cells)

Comment: @stovfl that link helped but i'm still running into the problem that it creates everything in one row as shown above.

Comment: Don't follow the questions code, use the approach from the last answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a Python [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=dictwriter#csv.DictWriter) to help with this. Each matching row can be assigned to a row dictionary. When a non-matching line is found, the row can then be written. `restval` is used in case one of the fields is missing.

For example:

```
import csv
import re

fields = ["TICKET NUMBER", "OLD SOURCE IPIP", "OLD SOURCE PORT", "HOST IP", "HOST PORT", "EXPLOIT"]
re_valid_field = re.compile('|'.join(fields))

with open('input.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fields, restval='')
    csv_output.writeheader()

    row = {}

    for line in f_input:
        if re_valid_field.match(line):
            key, sep, value = line.strip().partition(':')
            row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
        elif row:
            csv_output.writerow(row)
            row = {}

    # Any remaining row to be written?
    if row:
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This would create `output.csv` as follows:

```
TICKET NUMBER,OLD SOURCE IPIP,OLD SOURCE PORT,HOST IP,HOST PORT,EXPLOIT
2423,1.1.1.1,50,2.2.2.2,52,SomeRANDOMexploit
2423,1.1.1.1,50,2.2.2.2,52,SomeRANDOMexploit
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "writer7.py", line 15, in <module>  
    key, value = line.strip().split(':')  
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: There is probably a line in your file such as `TICKET NUMBER`, i.e. without any `:` to split on. I have adjusted the code to use `partition` instead of `split` to cope with that.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Now If I could just combine the two Functions into one script.